задержка перед исполнением программы vs code
В VS code появилась проблема при которой после запуска программы на python и ее исполнением есть задержка где то в 3 секунды, и дело именно в IDE, ибо в терминале всё хорошо. Пробовал переустанавливать и то и другое,но проблема не ушла. Кто то сказал почистить кэш у code, безуспешно. Может у кого есть решение?

Могу поклясться, я уже видел этот вопрос сегодня...

может это был мой, я его удалял и переспорсил)

Зачем тогда удаляли?

мне не понравилась формулировка и хотелось просто его пересоздать, в общем просто мои тараканы в голове

Ок ._. Теперь я хотя бы знаю, что это были вы))
